# TinyMCE not showing on Angular

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am trying to make my TinyMCE plugin work, here's what I've tried so far:

Index.html

```
<head>
 <script src="./assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea1',
    plugins: 'code',
    toolbar: 'code'
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app></app>
</body>
```

Child.html

```
<div class="mb-2">
  <textarea id="mytextarea1"></textarea>
</div>
```

It displays the textarea but the plugin doesn't seem working. Any inputs?

Comment: Is that AngularJS (1.X) or the new Angular (2+)?

Answer (score 0):

To add TinyMCE to your Angular project, use the official TinyMCE Angular integration component. See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/.